# RoR: Model Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

(sorry for my english)
If i have 3 model, :Movie :Actor :Connect, how can i make id Assocations?
Connect model have a movie_id:integer and a actor_id:integer, and i wanna make connections between actors and movies.

Comment: Start by having a look at this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

in Movie model:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connects
  has_many :actors, :through => :connects
end
```

in Actor model:

```
class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connects
  has_many :movies, :through => :connects
end
```

in Connect model:

```
class Connect < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :actor
end
```

Comment: this drop an error
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: connects.movie_id: SELECT "actors".* FROM "actors" INNER JOIN "connects" ON "actors"."id" = "connects"."actor_id" WHERE "connects"."movie_id" = 15

Comment: Most probably you have to run migrations. Try this in your console. `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to do a HABTM (Has And Belongs To Many) relationship

check these links on the same

1) [rails api](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many)

2) rails cast [(free but old)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes?autoplay=true), and [paid](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised)

3) [one my my sample project on HABTM](https://github.com/sameera207/HABTMsample)